# (lldb) Run time Error on Xcode Version 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

When I try to run my Xcode project on my device (iPhone), Xcode is creating a runtime error. Project works fine in iOS Simulator.

I have: 
Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)
iOS Simulator Version 8.1 (550.3)
iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1
Project lang: Swift

backtrace info:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x4e2ca, 0x1fed108c dyld`dyld_fatal_error, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)
  * frame #0: 0x1fed108c dyld`dyld_fatal_error
    frame #1: 0x1fed3902 dyld`dyld::halt(char const*) + 74
    frame #2: 0x1fed3b1a dyld`dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 278
    frame #3: 0x303dc094 libdyld.dylib`dyld_stub_binder + 20
    frame #4: 0x000f7df4 GCFSoccer`GCFSoccer.FavoritesTableViewController.init (aDecoder=0x18085000, self=0x17e31110)(coder : ObjectiveC.NSCoder) -> GCFSoccer.FavoritesTableViewController + 104 at FavoritesTableViewController.swift:19
    frame #5: 0x000f80e4 GCFSoccer`@objc GCFSoccer.FavoritesTableViewController.init (GCFSoccer.FavoritesTableViewController.Type)(coder : ObjectiveC.NSCoder) -> GCFSoccer.FavoritesTableViewController + 68 at FavoritesTableViewController.swift:0
    frame #6: 0x25f2ef20 UIKit`-[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 192
    frame #7: 0x25ff5d9e UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 850
    frame #8: 0x25ff5cf4 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 680
    frame #9: 0x25ff5a3e UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 334
    frame #10: 0x25e4bdf8 UIKit`-[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1016
    frame #11: 0x25e5eeea UIKit`-[UINavigationController initWithCoder:] + 46
    frame #12: 0x25ff5d9e UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 850
    frame #13: 0x25ff5cf4 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 680
    frame #14: 0x25ff5a3e UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 334
    frame #15: 0x25e4bdf8 UIKit`-[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 1016
    frame #16: 0x25e69f02 UIKit`-[UITabBarController initWithCoder:] + 46
    frame #17: 0x000c7648 GCFSoccer`GCFSoccer.MainTabBarController.init (aDecoder=0x18085000, self=0x17d4b120)(coder : ObjectiveC.NSCoder) -> GCFSoccer.MainTabBarController + 160 at MainTabBarController.swift:0
    frame #18: 0x000c7724 GCFSoccer`@objc GCFSoccer.MainTabBarController.init (GCFSoccer.MainTabBarController.Type)(coder : ObjectiveC.NSCoder) -> GCFSoccer.MainTabBarController + 68 at MainTabBarController.swift:0
    frame #19: 0x25f2ef20 UIKit`-[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 192
    frame #20: 0x25ff5d9e UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 850
    frame #21: 0x25ff5a3e UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 334
    frame #22: 0x25f2eb62 UIKit`-[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 150
    frame #23: 0x25ff5d9e UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 850
    frame #24: 0x25ff5cf4 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 680
    frame #25: 0x25ff5a3e UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 334
    frame #26: 0x25f2e24e UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 958
    frame #27: 0x260c3e9c UIKit`-[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 196
    frame #28: 0x25dd36d4 UIKit`-[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 64
    frame #29: 0x25dd29f8 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1116
    frame #30: 0x25ddd378 UIKit`__84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 36
    frame #31: 0x25dd1386 UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 130
    frame #32: 0x28e3e0e8 FrontBoardServices`__31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 12
    frame #33: 0x2267839c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    frame #34: 0x22677660 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 216
    frame #35: 0x22675de2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 762
    frame #36: 0x225c4210 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    frame #37: 0x225c4022 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #38: 0x25bd53ee UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 558
    frame #39: 0x25bd01d0 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1440
    frame #40: 0x0010c824 GCFSoccer`top_level_code + 72 at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #41: 0x0010c860 GCFSoccer`main + 48 at AppDelegate.swift:0
(lldb)
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: are there any changes in the optimization settings? does it work if you bulid for debug, but not for release?

Comment: wow by default it was building for debug. I changed it to release, now it is working fine on my iPhone.

Comment: that smells like a compiler error. You should submit a radar at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: How did you ever get past this? It just started happening with me on Xcode 6.4, out of the blue. No idea why.